# Visual SVN for VS2010 is holding on to stale reference to deleted branch

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, branch, visualsvn

I'm using the **Visual SVN** client plug-in for **Visual Studio 2010**.

I recently created a **branch** in Visual SVN, but I accidentally saved it in to the wrong location, specifying "NewName" under "trunk/" instead of under "branches/".  Before I realized the error, I had switched between the 2 version in the **"Subversion Branch URL" dropdown** in the toolbar several times.

After creating a new branch under "branches/", I deleted the the original branch, but the dropdown in the Visual SVN plugin is still holding on to a reference to the stale/deleted branch. I'm unable to delete the dropdown reference to "trunk/NewName".  Is there a way to do this?

I've even tried editing the registry, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to clear the list of most recently used branches you should delete the **.suo** file of your solution. Visual Studio must be closed when you delete this file.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not clear out the "Subversion Branch URL" dropdown in the Visual Studio 2010 toolbar from VisualSVN. After clearing the URL history, the stale entry is still present.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN just keeps list of 50 most recent branches. This list stored in Visual Studio .suo file. VisualSVN doesn't access server to retrieve this list.